# What conversion happens in the following expression?

Tags: c, type-conversion

In the following expression, what conversion happens?

```
long long a;
long long b;
double c;
b=a*c;
```

suppose the `long long` type is 8-byte.

If `a` and `b` are both `int`, then in the expression `b = a * c`, `a` will be converted to `double` and does multiplication with `c`, and the result will be converted to `int` and assigned to `b`.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: This would make more sense if you also assigned some values to the variables, or at least implied that you did. As it stands now, it could be optimized out, I think.

Comment: You might want to read more about [implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion), especially the section about [usual arithmetic conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions).

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Why would you think conversion using `long long`s would be different from when using `int`s?

Answer (score 2):

```
b=a*c;
```

is equivalent to:

```
b=(long long) ( (double)a * c );
```

So there are two conversions involved, first from `long long` to `double` and second from `double` result to `long long`

For more details check [this page from Joachim Pileborg's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335601/what-conversion-happens-in-the-flowing-expression#comment50655882_31335601) comment

Answer (score 1):

As per `C11` standard, chapter §6.3.1.8, *Usual arithmetic conversions*

> ....Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double, the other
>   operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>   corresponding real type is `double`.

So, your statement is essentially,

```
b= (long long)( (double)a * c );
```

that is, for the `*` operand, `c` is `double`, so value of `a` is converted to a `double` value, the multiplication is performed, the result is of type `double` and finally, that value is being converted to `long long`, when assigned to `b`, as per the type of `b` itself.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause
>   conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to
>   determine a common real type for the operands and result....This
>   pattern is called **the usual arithmetic conversions:**
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double,
>   the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a
>   type whose corresponding real type is double

And (6.5.16 Assignment operators)

> 3. **The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand** 
>      would have after lvalue conversion.

and (6.5.16.1 Simple assignment)

> 2 Insimple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted
>   to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored
>   in the object designated by the left operand.

Thus in this statement

```
b = a * c;
```

at first object `a` is converted to type `double` and the evaluated right operand has type `double`. After that the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression that has the type of the left operand that is the result of `a * c` is converted to `long long int`.

Take into account that even if `c` is equal to 1 expression `a * c` is not necessary equal to `a * 1` due to the conversions

Consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main( void )
{
    long long a = LLONG_MAX;
    long long b;
    double c = 1;

    printf( "a = %lld\n", a );
    printf( "c = %lf\n", c );

    b = a * c;

    printf( "b = %lld\n", b );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
a = 9223372036854775807
c = 1.000000
b = -9223372036854775808
```